# Clicking <span> element > JavaScript output document.activeElement VS. event.target

Tags: javascript

I’m newbie in JavaScript. Here’s my code below.

Upon clicking a button, I understand why event.target returns **span** object (because that’s the innermost element I click. correct?).

My doubt is, going by same logic why document.activeElement returns **button** object and not **span** object? Isn't it the **span** element that should be active when I click the **button** or not?!

Thanks in advance for your clarifications :=)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetActive () {
            if (document.activeElement) {
               var output = document.getElementById ("output");
               output.innerHTML = document.activeElement + ’-’ + event.target
             }
        }
     </script>
 </head>
 <body onclick="GetActive ();">    
    Click anywhere on the page to get the active element <input id="myInput" value="input field" />

   <button> <span>Sample button</span> </button>

   <div id="output"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: it is nice to see if you click all at the edge of the button, `event.target` is `button` and not `span`. That is because the `span` tag does not 'cover' the entire `button`

Comment: thanks a lot for clarification. it helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `document.activeElement` reports the element which is currently focused (or will receive keystrokes).

> [Returns the **currently focused element**, that is, the **element that will get keystroke events** if the user types any. This attribute is read only.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

Since elements like `span` and `div` can't receive keystrokes or be focused on (by tabbing to them) ordinarily, they won't ever be the `activeElement`. Those tags will be the activeElement only when they *can* receive keystrokes or be "active", such as when you've made them `contenteditable` or given them a `tabindex`.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jepanakopu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks you very much!